# Select certain row values and make them columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like the below:

```
+-------------------------+-------------+------+--------+-------------+--------+--+
|                         | impressions | name | shares | video_views |  diff  |  |
+-------------------------+-------------+------+--------+-------------+--------+--+
| _ts                     |             |      |        |             |        |  |
| 2016-09-12 23:15:04.120 |           1 | Vidz |      7 |       10318 | 15mins |  |
| 2016-09-12 23:16:45.869 |           2 | Vidz |      7 |       10318 | 16mins |  |
| 2016-09-12 23:30:03.129 |           3 | Vidz |     18 |       29291 | 30mins |  |
| 2016-09-12 23:32:08.317 |           4 | Vidz |     18 |       29291 | 32mins |  |
+-------------------------+-------------+------+--------+-------------+--------+--+
```

I am trying to build a dataframe to feed to a regression model, and I'd like to parse out specific rows as features.  To do this I would like the dataframe to resemble this

```
+-------------------------+------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                         | name | 15min_shares | 15min_impressions | 15min_video_views | 30min_shares | 30min_impressions | 30min_video_views |
+-------------------------+------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| _ts                     |      |              |                   |                   |              |                   |                   |
| 2016-09-12 23:15:04.120 | Vidz |            7 |                 1 |             10318 |           18 |                 3 |             29291 |
+-------------------------+------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

What would be the best way to do this?  I think this would be easier if I were only trying to select 1 row (15mins), just parse out the unneeded rows and pivot.

However, I need 15min and 30min features and am unsure on how to proceed of the need for these columns

Comment: Do you now about [`pandas.DataFrame.get_dummies()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), it is not exactly what you asked for, but might be a workaround.

Comment: The output you want doesn't make sense. Your _ts row with 2016-09-12 23:15:04.120 does not have any 30 min impressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take subsets of your `DF` to include rows for 15mins and 30mins and concatenate them by backfilling `NaN` values of first row(15mins) with that of it's next row(30mins) and dropping off the next row(30mins) as shown:

```
prefix_15="15mins"
prefix_30="30mins"

fifteen_mins = (df['diff']==prefix_15)
thirty_mins = (df['diff']==prefix_30)

df = df[fifteen_mins|thirty_mins].drop(['diff'], axis=1)

df_ = pd.concat([df[fifteen_mins].add_prefix(prefix_15+'_'),          \
                 df[thirty_mins].add_prefix(prefix_30+'_')], axis=1)   \
                .fillna(method='bfill').dropna(how='any')

del(df_['30mins_name'])
df_.rename(columns={'15mins_name':'name'}, inplace=True)
df_
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

stacking to pivot and collapsing your columns

```
df1 = df.set_index('diff', append=True).stack().unstack(0).T
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

To see just the first row

```
df1.iloc[[0]].dropna(1)
```

[image]